# How do I extract the K "smallest" elements from a list of objects?

Tags: java, list, pointers

I'm looping through a List to find a particular entry, then assigning that to a variable and trying to remove it later. It's easier to demo than to explain.

```
ArrayList<Example> list1 = populate();

Example ex1 = list1.get(0);
Example ex2 = ex1;
list1.remove(ex2);
```

I know this likely has something to do with Java's inability to handle pointers, but a viable solution would be great.

Edit: To elaborate, this is a brief example of my code rather than giving you the full thing. What I'm doing is iterating through a list to find the lowest 10 numbers. My technique is to go through the list, find the lowest and add it to another list, then remove that number from the original list and repeat. But my list is made of objects which have an int value inside them, rather than a list of integers.

```
for(0 to 9){
    for(0 to list.size){
        if(list.get(x) < smallest)
            smallest = list.get(x)
    }
    smallestList.add(smallest);
    list.remove(smallest)
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, exactly what you would like to achieve?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean here. Removing elements from a list is fine, assigning them to variables is also fine, but since ex2 and ex1 are the same here, you will remove ex1. Is that what you want?

Comment: This looks fine to me. What's the question?

Comment: Please post the full question next time. Your question has totally changes its meaning after edit

Comment: Your initial question has completely changed :)

Comment: Looks like you want to sort a list why don't you look at the Comparator and Collections.sort()

Answer (score 2):

I would sort the list. Then, I would create a list with those 10 smallest objects and change the original list `list1` to contain the remaining objects. Something like:

```
Collection.sort(list1);
ArrayList<Example> yourSmallestElements = (ArrayList<Example>)(list1.sublist(0, 9).clone());
list1.removeAll(yourSmallestElements);
```

NOTE: I cloned the sublist because `sublist()` only returns a *view* of the list `list1`, and that's not what you want here.

Your class `Example` can implement "Comparable" so that you can define how they need to be compared. You will need to implement the method `compareTo()`. Something like this:

```
public class Example implements Comparable<Example> {
    private int integerVal = <a value>;

    public int compareTo(Example exampleObject) {
        return exampleObject.integerVal - this.integerVal;
    }   
}
```

Have a look at [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/), more precisely the class that begins as follows:

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>{
```

Comment: This is great solution...but the question states -- "then remove that number from the original list". Your method modifies the original list and will not remove elements.

Comment: That's a point. But then he can keep only the biggest elements of the sorted list anyway...

Comment: @Bill But the question was (is?) mis-asked. The real question is: which is the best way to find the smallest K numbers in a List ? Then, +1

Comment: @Andrea I agree, but he might have a use case of actually doing it the way he asked in his question :)

Comment: @Bill The first question was son of the algorithm thinked by OP. After the edit revealed the *real* question, then IMHO there is no need to follow the original specs, because it is now clear that they wasn't a requisite, but a draft of one possible way to do this thing. Also the title of this question should be edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort your objects...

```
Example e;
int min=-1; // assuming the list has +ve numbers only
for (Example elem : yourList)
{
if ( elem.gtVaribale() <= min ) //assuming you have variable field in your object
{
  e = elem;
  min = elem.getVariable();
}
}
yourList.remove(e);

//repeat this for remaining elements of the list

//you can create another sorted list, and do sortedList.add(e), so that sortedList
//have objects in ascending order (of the variable you want to sort) of objects you had in yourList
```

This is just a pseudoCode and I have not compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will have to override the comparable method for class Example.
You have to let compiler know which way it should compare your e variable to its list's elements so as to remove it.